# Can plugins in CustusX implement several interfaces at once?

Tags: plugins

I want to create a plugin (or two?) for [CustusX](http://www.custusx.org/). The plugin is thought to be used to guide a user through a recording workflow. At the same time, it is supposed to take an image stream, and provide another image stream (original stream + overlay image).

So it's supposed to have a GUI component (and as such should implement GUIExtenderService) but it should as well provide StreamerService. Is that possible together in one plugin or do I have to split it up in two plugins?

Comment: I wanted to create a custusx tag, but I don't have enough reputation. I consider this an issue related only to this software package, so I would appreciate such a tag (this is along the lines of this answer: adding a comment and ask for creation). It seems as well that it is the intention of authors that questions are asked here (From their developers page: "Post a question on stackoverflow.com/search?q=custusx, use the tag custusx")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one plugin can provide several services. Plugins and services are two separate [OSGi concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). CustusX bases its plugin framework on the [CTK](http://www.commontk.org) implementation of OSGi.

In general it is preferable to bundle one feature within a plugin. If that feature requires several services (typically both backend and frontend) in order to be realized then you should keep to one plugin in order to minimize the number of plugins and keep related code in one place.